# Serving images across mobile and web

Tags: javascript, android, html, web, base91

I need to build a web portal that uploads images to a database. These images will be displayed in an android app, and the web portal.

The common method I use when dealing strictly with apps is as follows:

- compress the picture
- encode it to a [base91](http://base91.sourceforge.net/) string
- send to server for storage

How do I achieve this in the context of a website(using javascript or python)? particularly the encode/decode (Base91) part.

ps: My experience with web is very basic.

Comment: `compress the picture`. If it is a jpg file there is nothing to compress.

Comment: `encode it to a Base91 string`. Base91? Whats that? Strange. You first want to compress. To reduce the amount of bytes you have to transfer i think. And now you want to base64 encode? You get 30% more bytes to transfer. Bad idea. Better just upload the file.

Comment: What has this webportal to do with Android?

Comment: Who is uploading the images to the webserver?

Comment: if its 5mb, i compress it to about 2-300kb, then encode to base91(<33% increase in size) so i can store it as a string.

Comment: The web portal is where the content of the platform is generated. This content(the pictures) is consumed by the android app

Comment: So base91 exists. Learned again something.

Comment: If the content is generated in the web portal then i do not understand what has to be uploaded.

Comment: You are not compressing your files i think but resizing your images. Confusing talk.

Comment: Generated/uploaded, i mean the same thing sir. And no, im not resizing the images, im compressing them(or atleast i want to)

Comment: How would you compress a jpg file of 2MB to 300KB?

Comment: `Generated/uploaded, i mean the same thing`. Difficult talking with you in this way. As a programmer you could be more exact.

Comment: `This content(the pictures) is consumed by the android app`. So the android app will not upload pictures?

Comment: "Difficult talking with you in this way. As a programmer you could be more exact" ok, lets stick to uploaded.

Comment: "So the android app will not upload pictures?" no it wont